# Python PulP Timeslot allocation optimization Problem

Tags: python, optimization, allocation, pulp

I have another problem in a Python PulP optimization Model:

There are Employees and a Dict with keys from 0 to 143 (Timeslots between 06:00 and 18:00 in 5 Minute steps). Every Timeslots has 0 to n booked appointments. The Goal is to reach an even Allocation of all booked appointments. In my Code below, this works fine.
But this model doesnt consider the fakt, that one appoint can be represented in more Timeslots:
Example: Customer A books an appointment at 06:00. But the task lasts 2 Timeslots. The value of Timeslot 0 an 1 is 1 () 6:00 and 06:05. Of course both of the Timeslots should have the same employee.
The Constraint which tells the Algorythm, that the allocation should be even, is a soft constraint. So its possible to violate it.

I would Formulate my missing constraint like this: If there is an Appointment directly after another, the same employee should get this one.

I know, that if there are two different Appointments, one after another (Cutomer A - 08:00 - 08:10 and Customer B 08:10 - 08-20) the same Employee will work on both appointments. But in this case, it doenst matter. Only if you have an idea how to fix that two, please tell me

```
def problem_modulation(date):
    prob = LpProblem("equally_employee_allocation",LpMinimize)

    #Dictionary mit Mitarbeitern, solange diese nicht im Urlaub sind. (inkl allen weiteren Informationen)
    employee_dict = {1:"Steve", 2:"Marcus", 3:"Rodger", 4:"Sara"}
    employee_count = len(employee_dict)

    #Dict aller Slots und wie viele Terminen zu diesem Zeitslot bearbeitet werden müssen

    slot_appo_dict = {1:0,2:0,3:1,4:1,5:2,6:2} # One Appointment at 6:10 and 6:15 two at 6:20 and 6:25

    # Summe aller Termine
    appointment_sum = sum(slot_appo_dict.values())

    # Durchschnittliche Termine pro MA
    avg_appointments = appointment_sum/employee_count

    #Binärvariablen, welche angeben, ob ein Mitarbeiter einem Termin zugeteilt wurde, oder nicht.
    empl_appo_bin = LpVariable.dicts("employ_appoi_bin", (slot_appo_dict, employee_dict),cat=LpBinary)

    #Variable, welche die Anzahl der Termine des jeweiligen Mitarbeiters angibt
    empl_appo_count= LpVariable.dicts("employ_appoi_count", employee_dict, cat=LpInteger, lowBound=0)



    ##### Zielfunktion #####
    prob+=lpSum(empl_appo_count[e] for e in employee_dict)

    ##### Nebenbedingungen #####

    #Die Anzahl der aufgeteilten Mitarbeiter auf einen Slot muss der denen der gebuchten Termine entsprechen:
    for slot in slot_appo_dict:
        prob += lpSum(empl_appo_bin[slot][e] for e in employee_dict) == slot_appo_dict[slot]

    for empl in employee_dict:
        # Die Anzahl der zugewiesenen Termine von Mitarbeiter M:
        prob += empl_appo_count[empl] == lpSum(empl_appo_bin[slot][empl] for slot in slot_appo_dict)

        #elastic Constraint: Abweichung von der durchschnittlichen Anzahl der bearbeiteten Termine wird       bestraft
        exp1 = LpAffineExpression(empl_appo_count[empl])
        flex_constraint1 = LpConstraint(e=exp1, name=f"equal_allocation{empl}", sense=0, rhs=avg_appointments)
        prob.extend(flex_constraint1.makeElasticSubProblem(penalty=0.1, proportionFreeBound=0.15))




    prob.writeLP("data/equally_allocation.lp")
    prob.solve()
```

I tryed several things to get this work. Pulps elastic constraint doesnt allow variables on the right hand side.

Comment: Not reproducible since we don't have `get_employees`. Please provide a representative, complete example.

Comment: I think you need to put a little more thought into this.  Especially, as you said in your other question, this is part of a school assignment.  Having some kind of “continuity constraint” isn’t necessarily trivial and there’s nothing in your code that represents an attempt at making one.  In your data, would you intend for 1 employee to be assigned to the (presumed) continuous task in slots 3,4,5,6?

Comment: Here’s a hint to get you started:  Reformulate your data.  Right now your data has no information about duration of the appointments.  Restructure it so that each appointment has a starting period and a duration (in periods or such.) Then you can construct variables to reflect assignment and such.

Comment: I tryed this a couple hours ago. I added a Dict which has information of the Starting slot an the duration: I Will post this attempt below. But this Workaound only brings "infeasible" solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code above, I tried this:

```
 for empl in employee_dict:
   for slot in slot_appo_dict:
       for i in appointment_length_dict[slot]:
           prob += lpSum(empl_appo_bin[slot+s][empl] for s in range(i)) == empl_appo_bin[slot][empl]*i
```

`appointment_length_dict` is a `Dict` which has information about the starting slot and the Duration of this Appointment. The value of this `Dict` has the form ob list, because there could be more than one Appointmentment at the same slot

Comment: This does not actually provide any information to future readers with the same problem. Please [edit] this post to include what the solution was and any additional information that could be useful to others with the same problem.